# Analogue of Thomassen's theorem, for a $C_7$ colouring

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

I am trying to show that $ \forall \alpha >0, \exists C(\alpha)$:

*If $G$ is an $n$-vertex graph with minimum degree at least $\alpha n$, then either $G$ contains $C_7$ as a subgraph, or it is $C(\alpha)$-colourable.*

My attempt until now, includes the corresponding proof of Thomassen for $C_5$ instead, along with the proof of Tomasz Łuczak and Stéphan Thomassé but I do not see a possible way into extending the result to $C_7$.

Comment: If you don't care too much about the tightness of the bound you can utilize the following fact: If $G$ has no path of length $t$ then $\chi(G) \leq t$. With that you can prove a lemma that looks like: let $v \in V$ s.t for each $w \in V \setminus N(v)$, we have $N(v) \cap N(w) = \emptyset$. Then if $G$ is $C_{7}$-free, $G$'s chromatic number is bounded (show that the neighbourhood of $v$ and the other vertices can't have long paths, say paths of size 100000 if you want, and then colour the neighbourhood and the others with distinct colours). Then you should be able to prove the claim.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will need to go through this a lot, before coming back to you. Nevertheless, I now have at least a way to work. Again, thank you.